# Detect Returning User in a Rails3 + Devise application

Tags: ruby-on-rails, cookies, devise

I'm looking for a solution, to reach the desired behaviour.
Running a Rails3 application where authentication is handle by Devise. I want to detect any user coming back to the site while already signed in (with the `remember_me` cookie).

My aim is to redirect him to a specific page (as I already do it on `after_sign_in_path_for`).

My very problem is not to detect if a user is `signed_in?`, but to be sure he wasn't navigating on the site just tow minutes before (I prefer to avoid strategy based an time...)

Any guess ?

Comment: Not at all clear to me what you are wanting here.  You want to detect if a user has been signed in recently, but don't want to do it based on time?  This doesn't make sense ...

Comment: Sorry if I was unclear, I wanted to detect if a user signed in based on the remember_me cookie is returning to the site. But I found a good solution based on the rails session cookie (see the edit of my question). thx anyway

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My own answer, to my question...

I posted the question too quickly.

The solution is quite simple, Rails create a session cookie after each request, we just need to check if it exists or not :

```
def user_returning?
  user_signed_in? && session[:session_id].blank?
end
```

I was mixing Devise session wich can subsiste between browser closings, and session cookie which are destroyed after each browser closing.

`user_returning?` allow me to know if a user is coming back to the site, while he is already signed in...